# How can I declare these as string?

Tags: ruby

```
[^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\]^_`~]
```

I can't use double quotes, I can't use `%q<symbol>string<symbol>` because it contains all possible symbols (at least it should).

Comment: I have literally no idea what you've just asked there.

Comment: @MaxWoolf, sorry, edited. Need whole first line be a string, but, it contains double quotes and symbols, which will break string declaration

Comment: It's still not clear what you want, but it looks like you want to ignore space and all punctuation characters and you forgot the delimiting `/.../` or `%r/.../`.

Comment: @theTinMan, rails method for requesting database queries is where("string argument"), and I need some parts of argument string to be equal this string

Answer (score 2):

```
irb(main):001:0> '[^\s!"#$%&\'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\\\\]^_`~]'
=> "[^\\s!\"\#$%&'()*+,\\-./:;<=>?\\[\\\\\\]^_`~]"
```

Escape quote.

```
irb(main):012:0* <<'eos'.chomp
irb(main):013:0' [^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\]^_`~]
irb(main):014:0' eos
=> "[^\\s!\"\#$%&'()*+,\\-./:;<=>?\\[\\\\\\]^_`~]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "HEREDOC"

```
my_string = <<-eos.gsub(/\s+/,'')
   [^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\]^_`~]
eos
```

Ruby 2.0, working as it should.

Comment: this is not correct I think. I am getting below - `>> my_string = <<eos
    [^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\]^_`~]
eos
SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
    [^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\]^_`~]
            ^
(irb):2: unterminated string meets end of file
 from /home/kirti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
`

Answer (score 1):

Below will work also

```
%q{[^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\]^_`~]}
#=> "[^\\s!\"\#$%&'()*+,\\-./:;<=>?\\[\\\\]^_`~]"
```

or

```
s = %q<[^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\]^_`~]>
s # => "[^\\s!\"\#$%&'()*+,\\-./:;<=>?\\[\\\\]^_`~]"
```

Comment: This results in an incorrect number of backslashes between the brackets both ways.  That is, `[\\]` rather than `[\\\]`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you *can* use double-quotes or `%Q`, it just takes more work than single-quotes or `%q`.

I would use single-quotes, since you then only need to escape singe-quotes (`'`) and meaningful backslashes (`\`):

```
puts '[^\s!"#$%&\'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\\\]^_`~]'
[^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\]^_`~]
```

With double-quotes, you need to escape double-quotes (`"`), pounds/hashes (`#`), percents (`%`), and all backslashes, not just meaningful ones:

```
puts "[^\\s!\"\#$\%&'()*+,\\-./:;<=>?\\[\\\\\\]^_`~]"
[^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\]^_`~]
```

You don't use curly brackets, so `%q{}` only needs meaningful backslashes to be escaped:

```
puts %q{[^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\\\]^_`~]}
[^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\]^_`~]
```

Ruby properly handles nesting with `%Q` and `%q`, so this works just as well, even though you used `<` and `>`, since they happen to be used conveniently balanced:

```
puts %q<[^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\\\]^_`~]>
[^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\]^_`~]
```

Last, if you don't want to deal with escaping any characters, you could always just paste the strange string as-is into a file and read it:

```
puts File.read('strange.txt').chomp
[^\s!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\]^_`~]
```

Answer (score 0):

`` x = '[^\s!"#$%&\'()*+,\-./:;<=>?\[\\\]^_`~]' ``

But are you sure you don't want to define a regular expression?

Comment: No, cause these goes as part of SQL request

Comment: @JoeHalfFace: What does this have to do with SQL?

Comment: woops you're right, thanks. I was under the false impression a quote would escape as well in a single quoted string, but I needed a backslash. Fixed the answer

Comment: Joe, if you're trying to incorporate user input into a SQL statement, you're doing it wrong.  Use placeholders / bind variables instead, because you will almost certainly overlook something that will leave your app vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

> it contains all possible symbols (at least it should)

So you need a string containing all symbols?

The [ASCII printable characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) are within the character range 32..126. I'd use this range to create the string:

```
(32.chr..126.chr).grep(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/).join
#=> " !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"
```

#### Explanation:

- `(32.chr..126.chr)` creates the entire character range
- `grep(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/)` removes the "non-symbol" characters `0-9`, `a-z` and `A-Z`
- `join` joins the remaining characters